# Warning: The method start() from the type Thread is deprecated

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I got this warning:

```
The method start() from the type Thread is deprecated
```

I know a lot of Thread methods are deprecated but is the start() deprecated?
If so, what should I use instead?

**Edit:**
Is it an IDE config issue? How to remove this warning?

[image]

[image]

Comment: `java.lang.Thread#start()`?

Comment: Doesn't look deprecated to me.... are you sure you have the correct thread class imported? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

Comment: Yep, that's what I thought but I got this warning when coding Android (Java) with Eclipse.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be deprecated in android either http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#start()

Comment: What does show the '1 quick fix available' hint?

Comment: I use Threads in Android 4 and it's not deprecated. Can you show the import of the class?

Comment: Add @SuppressWarnings 'deprecation' to 'someMethod'

Comment: Not a solution indeed, my bet is that there's some mess up with the importing class. `start()` is not deprecated.

Comment: Probably something's wrong with my Eclipse or lint?

Comment: What is `this`? I mean, in what `Context` are you running this?

Comment: this is service. Anyway, the warning is everywhere not only in this class.

Comment: I think it's a problem in the IDE. I try a similar code here and no warning is shown.

Comment: If start were deprecated, we would be in serious trouble...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be an SDK issue. (I used a custom android.jar.) Sorry, I didn't think about this when I asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

The method start() from the Thread class is not deprecated.

Please check the list of deprecated API.
[Deprecated Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/deprecated-list.html#method)

It seems that some eclipse problem.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it's depecreated (at least that is not Showing in android studio). Have you try run() instead?

Comment: Calling `run()` directly is not going to execute code on a separate thread.